# Sorting methods in alphabetical orders [QT Creator]

Tags: qt, ide, qt-creator

I'm using QT creator and I would like to know if there is a way to automatically sort all my methods in this order :

1. Constructor
2. Destructor
3. The rest of methods in alphabetical orders

My project is getting quite big, so I would like to know if there is a way to do this automatically, since it will take a lot of time otherwise

Comment: If you want to do this operation once, it's not Qt Creator-specific, as you can do it with any tool that can do this. If you want automatic sorting of new code on-the-fly, it's not a big deal: if you insert new method in correct position of a header and ask Qt Creator to create implementation, it will insert it between the method above and the method below as they appear in the header.

Comment: You have to write a refactoring plugin to do that for you. AFAIK, no such plugin exists.